# What is the shape of the $n$-gon which gives the maximum of a function?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polygons, isoperimetric-problems

What is the shape of the $n$-gon $P_1P_2\cdots P_n$ which gives the maximum of $A_n$? The quantity $A_n$ is defined by
$$ A_n = \frac{{\sum_{i\lt{j}\le{n}}{\lvert P_i P_j\rvert}^2}-{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lvert P_i P_{i+1}\rvert}^2}}{{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\lvert P_i P_{i+1}\rvert}^2}} $$
Here, $\lvert P_i P_j \rvert$ is the Euclidean length of the line segment from $P_i$ to $P_j$. Note that $P_{n+1}=P_1$ and that the $n$-gon can be either convex or concave.

I'm interested in $A_n$ because I knew the fact that the maximum of $A_4$ is $1$ only if $P_1P_2P_3P_4$ is a parallelogram. I've already proved the case $n=4$, but I don't have any good idea for $n\ge5$.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the meaning of the notation $P_i P_j^2$? Do you mean $|P_i P_j|^2$, the square of the Euclidean length of the segment from $P_i$ to $P_j$? Or are you implying some type of multiplication between $P_i$ and $P_j$?

Comment: Voting to close pending clarification of what $P_iP_j^2$ means.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: Thank you very much for pointing it out. In this problem, ${P_{i}P_{j}}^2$ means the square of the Euclidean length of the segment from $P_i$ to $P_j$.

Comment: I edited the question to make the notation more explicit and standard.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade: Thank you very much.

Comment: Essentially the ratio is sum of diagonals$^2$ over sum of edges$^2$. For $n=5$, I suspect the max is achieved by the regular pentagon, $(3+\sqrt{5})/2 \approx 2.62$.

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: I think so. Though I've tried to prove that if the pentagon is not a regular pentagon, $A_5$ is not max, I'm facing difficulty.

Comment: Yes, it may be that the max is not uniquely achieved.

Comment: I got that $A_5\lt3$ for any pentagon by using the result that $A_4\le1$ for any quadrilateral and that there is no pentagon whose $A_5$ is 3.

Comment: I think I can prove that $A_5$ reaches the max only if the pentagon is a regular pentagon. Please judge whether my proof is correct or not. I use an transforming operation through which the value of $A_5$ doesn't change or increases. Here is the operation which consists of the following steps.

Comment: First, find the two adjacent edges which has the largest of $||$$P_iP_{i+1}$$|$$-$$|$$P_{i+1}P_{i+2}$$|$$|$, say $P_1P_2$ $\ge$ $P_2P_3$. Next, draw the circle $C_{13}$, the center is the midpoint $M_{13}$ of the line segment $P_1P_3$ and the radius is the line segment $M_{13}P_2$.

Comment: Next, draw the perpendicular bisector $L_{13}$ of the line segment $P_1P_3$. Final step is to determin an intersection $Q_2$ where the line $L_{13}$ crosses the circle $C_{13}$. This is the transforming operation.

Comment: The point $Q_2$ is outside of the circle $C_{45}$, the center is the midpoint $M_{45}$ of the edge $P_4P_5$ and the radius is the line segment $M_{45}P_2$. This means the following two.

Comment: $$|P_2P_1|^2+|P_2P_3|^2\le|Q_2P_1|^2+|Q_2P_3|^2$$ and  $$|P_2P_5|^2+|P_2P_4|^2\le|Q_2P_5|^2+|Q_2P_4|^2$$ Therefore, the $A_5$ for the pentagon $P_1Q_2P_3P_4P_5$ is larger than, or equals to the $A_5$ for the pentagon $P_1P_2P_3P_4P_5$. Note that the lengths of the other line segment is constant.

Comment: By using this transforming operation infinitely, you get the pentagon whose edges have the same length. Without loss of generality suppose that the pentagon whose edges have the same length $1$. Then, $A_5=2-\frac25W$. Here, $W=cosA+cosB+cosC+cosD+cosE$.

Comment: wrong: $$|P_2P_1|^2+|P_2P_3|^2\le|Q_2P_1|^2+|Q_2P_3|^2$$ right: $$|P_2P_1|^2+|P_2P_3|^2=|Q_2P_1|^2+|Q_2P_3|^2$$

Comment: $W$ is min only if the pentagon is a regular pentagon, so the proof is completed.

Comment: By the way, in Euclidean geometry $AB$ is the most standard way to denote the distance from $A$ to $B$. It was no need to edit the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The optimal shape is the regular $n$-gon and all its affine images.

I am going to optimize the ratio
$$
 \frac{\sum_{i<j} |P_iP_j|^2}{\sum_i|P_iP_{i+1}|^2}
$$
which differs from $A_n$ by 1. For the regular $n$-gon this ratio equals
$$
 \frac{n}{2(1-\cos\frac{2\pi}n)} .
$$
Let us prove that this is the maximum.

The maximum ratio equals the maximum $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ such that the quadratic form
$$
 P\mapsto Q_\lambda(P) := \sum |P_iP_j|^2-\lambda\sum|P_iP_{i+1}|^2
$$
is nonnegative definite. Here $P$ denotes a polygon $P_1\dots P_n$ regarded as a point in $\mathbb R^{2n}$, so $Q_\lambda$ is a quadratic form in $\mathbb R^{2n}$. If $\lambda$ is the maximum and $P$ is an optimal polygon, then $Q_\lambda(P)=0$.

By the Pythagorean theorem, the coordinate expression for $Q_\lambda(P)$ splits into 2 independent summands: one for $x$-coordinates of the vertices and a similar one for $y$-coordinates. Since the form is nonnegative on all configurations of points, it is also nonnegative on the projections to $x$- and $y$-lines, and both summands must be zero separately.

Thus we have reduced the problem to the 1-dimensional case. It remains to solve the similar problem for the from $Q_\lambda$ in $\mathbb R^n$:
$$
 Q_\lambda(x) = \sum (x_i-x_j)^2-\lambda\sum(x_i-x_{i+1})^2
$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$. By the way, this reduction also shows that, whatever the optimal shape is, it comes with all its affine images.

Now assume that $\lambda$ is the maximum ratio and $x=(x_i)$ is an optimal configuration on the line. Differentiating $Q_\lambda(x)$ with respect to $x_i$ yields
$$
 2n(x_i-a) -2\lambda(2x_i-x_{i-1}-x_{i+1})
$$
where $a$ is the arithmetic mean of $x_1,\dots,x_n$. The derivative must be zero, and by translation we may assume that $a=0$. This gives us a linear recurrence equation
$$
 x_{i+1}=-x_{i-1}+(\tfrac{n}{\lambda}-2)x_i .
$$
The solution must be $n$-periodic, so it is a linear combination of two geometric progressions whose ratios are two conjugate $n$th roots of unity. In other words, we have
$$
 x_k = A \cos k\varphi + B\sin k\varphi
$$
for some real constants $A$ and $B$, where $\varphi$ is a multiple of $\frac{2\pi}n$. (Notation $i$ is changed to $k$ to prevent confusion with complex numbers.) Then
$$
 \lambda = \frac{n}{2(1-\cos\varphi)} .
$$
Checking the condition $Q_\lambda(x)=0$ leaves the only possibility $\varphi=\frac{2\pi}n$ (for larger multiples, the quantity is strictly positive).

Thus the maximum ratio equals $\frac{n}{2(1-\cos\frac{2\pi}n)}$ and the  optimal polygons are those whose $x$- and $y$-coordinates are sequences of the above form. These are precisely affine images of a regular $n$-gon. The solution is the same in all dimensions, not only in the plane.

Comment: Wow! Beautiful argument!

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov: Many thanks! $$x_{i+1}=-x_{i-1}-(\frac{n}{\lambda}-2)x_i$$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes the sign was wrong, but it does not matter for the argument.